# How can I access the "public" directory with images from my API hosted on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, git, api, express, heroku

I have deployed my API on Heroku, and it includes a "public" directory where I store images. However, when I clone the repository from Heroku, the "public" directory is not included.

I need a solution to access the "public" directory and its images from my API hosted on Heroku. What steps should I follow to retrieve the images or ensure that the "public" directory is included when cloning the repository?

I appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to solve this issue. Thank you in advance!

I tried cloning the repo, but no success.

Comment: I'don't know how Heroku works,  is there something similiar to .`gitignore` mechanism while cloning?